# How to find the elements of order 2 in an infinitely large group?

Tags: group-theory

Given $$G=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\mid a=\pm1,b\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}$$

Which is clearly a group of infinite order, how would I find all elements of order 2? Is there a formula for this or do I need to use common sense or something?

Comment: Well, you have to consider what "order 2" means.

Comment: I know what it means. An element $g$ of order 2 would satisfy $g^2=e$.

Comment: (... and $g\neq e$.) Yes, that's the general definition. In this specific case, with these matrices, how does that relation manifest?

Comment: So now apply it to your $g$ and solve the resulting equations for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: So, if $g^2=0$ what can you conclude about $a$ and $b$? Have you tried?

Comment: Yup, you were right. I should stop looking for a formula and just use my brain... It would be all matrices such that a = -1 and b = any integer

Answer (score 3):

For the following to hold,$$\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

We need $a^2=1$, $ab+b=0$, $0=0$, and $1=1$. The last two conditions are obvious, so let's consider the non-obvious relations.

For $a^2=1$, $a=\pm1$. If $a=1$, then we need $2b=0$, which would force $b=0$, making the matrix the identity, which doesn't have order $2$.

If $a=-1$, then $-b+b=0$ regardless of $b$, so the elements of order $2$ are the members of the set $$\bigg\{\begin{bmatrix}-1&b\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\;\bigg\vert\;b\in\mathbb Z\bigg\}$$